# Bootstrap drop down not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

All of a sudden after making some change my bootstrap dropdowns are not working. I dont think i even touched the code for it. I am using cdn for my includes but thats not new.

Try clicking the Jobber Nav Button:
http://www.development.johndayers.com/p/#

CSS:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.3.0/webfont.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/main.css" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidesjs/3.0/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear. Just that it is hidden as overflow is suppressed in your container div : `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">`.

```
.navbar {
   overflow: hidden; /* remove this and it should come up.*/
}
```

Comment: This works. I have no idea what i was thinking when i added that line. I must have meant a different selector. Thanks for the help and sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: @JohnAyers no worries. It happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: visible !important` to `.container`. Your `main.css` file applies `overflow: hidden;` to `.container`. Twitter Bootstrap is designed to have `.container` around all content, and not only the header as you have.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This would work as well if i hadnt added a ridiculous line to my code.